# HTML5 controls are not working in JavaFX webview

Tags: java, html, javafx, htmlcontrols

I am using below tag in my JavaFX WebView standalone application in one of the page

**Input type number** which accepts characters also

```
<input type="number" id="qNumber"/>
```

**input type date** which is not rendering as a date control

```
<input type="date" id="qDate"/>
```

The text type input still accepting text in input but when I use this tag in the normal HTML page (Not in `JavaFX`) like writing it in notepad, it's working fine.

How to resolve this rendering issue? Or anything I am doing wrong in steps to registering the HTML file?

Note:

*My web engine user agent is **Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/538.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) JavaFX/8.0 Safari/538.19**.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a known bug as you can see [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8177114).

You can instead use [jquery date picker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) or something else for now.

Comment: Thanks for your response and suggestion , it worked for me